# Skill or having the ability to pack/organize space well

Tags: single-word-requests

How would one describe, having the ability to pack well.

Example: being able to pack/organize the car for a long trip. Or being able to organize a cabinet, refrigerator, or freezer?

Comment: The usual term for that cognitive skill is "Volume conservation". People who have it can estimate accurately the total volumes of many randomly-shaped containers and objects, and transfer that information usefully to their plans for filling and emptying.

Answer (score 1):

***Tetris master*** would communicate well in America at least -- from the pervasive computer/video game where differently shaped blocks fall and need to be organized quickly and efficiently to earn points.
e.g.

> Dang, John, you are a Tetris master!  I am calling you the next time I need help moving!

[image]
[(Ref.)](http://kotaku.com/5569820/packing-tips-from-a-tetris-master)